# requiring lodash modules with webpack

Tags: module, webpack, lodash, commonjs

I used to use lodash.js without any packaging like below:

```
if (_.isFunction(myFunc)) { ... }
```

Recently, I started using webpack. Now, it seems many functions such as isFunction are not part of the core module. So, the following works:

```
var _ = require("lodash/core");
var _isFunction = require("lodash/isFunction");
```

However, the above changes the syntax when I used lodash without webpack (no dot). Should I require like below:

```
_.isFunction = require("lodash/isFunction")
```

so, that to maintain the same syntax?

Comment: ```
var _ = require('lodash')
if(_.isFunction(myFunc))
```
should work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like the following, you import everything under one big lodash object:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

`_` (or whatever var you choose) will be filled with a bunch of functions:

```
_ = {
    isX: function... 
    isY: function... 
    // ... etc
}
```

Ie: it brings *everything* in.

When you do the following, it will import only the required module directly into the variable:

```
var anynameX = require('lodash/isX'); 
var anynameY = require('lodash/isY');
```

`anynameX` and `anynameY` can be anything.

In other words:

```
_.isX === anynameX;    
_.isY === anynameY;
```

So to answer your last question, you could do:

```
_.anynameX = require('lodash/isX');
```

but only if `_` already exists (and isn't frozen), for example:

```
var _ = {};
_.anynameX = require('lodash/isX');
```